# How to use expl3 command \str_case:nnF

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

Could someone please explain how `xparse`-`expl3` command `\str_case:nnF` works by an example? Are `str`
and `case` important here?

Please avoid  long (text) answers. I think if you explain the basics, I can use it wherever I want.

Comment: Hmmm... I do not understand well the question. `str_case:nnF` is the name of the command. It's described in `interface3` manual, page 64.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5Cstr_case%3AnnF%22+user%3A4427

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As short as I can:

```
\str_case:nnF { <string> }
  {
    { <case 1> } { <code 1> }
    { <case 2> } { <code 2> }
    ...
    { <case n> } { <code n> }
  }
  { <false code> }
```

The command will compare `<string>` with each `<case n>` string, in order, and if it finds a match, the corresponding `<code n>` is executed.  If no matches are found, `<false code>` is executed.

---

Example: suppose you have a macro to which the user passes some options, say, `above`, `center`, or `below`, and it runs some code depending on the option chosen, and raises an error if something nonsense is typed:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cfg_test:n #1
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { above  } { <'above' code> }
        { center } { <'center' code> }
        { below  } { <'below' code> }
      }
      { \msg_error:nn { cfg } { invalid-option } {#1} }
  }
```

then `\cfg_test:n {center}` would run `<'center' code>` and `\cfg_test: {wrong}` would raise an error (though if this were for an user interface, `l3keys` could be used instead).

---

An `expl3` *command* (variables are different) have a name of the form:

```latex
\<module>_<name>:<signature>
```

The `<module>` says where that command is from: `str` is `expl3`'s string module, so you know that `\str_case:nnF` operates on strings.

The `<name>` says what the command does: `case` is used in `expl3` for functions that behave as the `switch case` constructs in other programming languages.  `expl3`'s `\<whatever>_case:nn(TF)` functions *always* have the same general syntax as above: it only changes what type of comparison they perform.  `\int_case:nnF`, for example, does the same but it compares integers.

The `<signature>` tells you how many, and what type of arguments the command takes. `n` is a normal `{...}`-delimited argument, and `F` is the same as `n`, but it's executed if the command evaluates to `false` (now guess what `T` means).  Take a look at [`expl3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf): you'll find a description of all possible signatures and the kernel `<modules>`.  Then take a look at [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), where you'll find a description of what every `expl3` command does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please give a simple example. and I think I can write `\str_case:nnnnnnnF` ? Yes?

Comment: @C.F.G Example added.  No, `\<thing>_case:nn` is _always_ `:nn`: the second `n` takes  a list of `{<case>}{<code>}` pairs.  The available variations of this command are `\str_case:nn` and `\str_case:nn(TF)`.  `(TF)` means it can be only `T`, only `F`, or both `TF`.

Comment: Aha. Very helpful.

Comment: Now see I understand it or not: Is the output of this code 2?: `\str_case:nnF {dd}
  {
    {d} {$1$}
    {dd} {$2$}
  }
  {$3$}`

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, that's right (`$2$`, more precisely :-).  If you just want to count how may chars in a string you can do `\str_count:n {dd}` (will return 2).

Comment: Oooo. Is there a complete list of commands that can be connected to `\str` like `count`?

Comment: I see now why David Carlisle and  Ulrike Fischer persisting that `xparse` is easy to handle for amateurs.

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, as I said `str` is the module, and there are several `\str_<thing>` commands to manipulate strings.  Do take a look at [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf): _all_ `expl3` commands are listed there. You'll find the documentation for the string module on page 60.  / As for `expl3` _vs._ “usual TeX”: experienced TeX programmers criticise `expl3` because it's an all-new syntax to the same old TeX: it is a lot to learn for a thing you already know.  But if you're a novice, `expl3` is really a lot easier to understand at first contact.